# How to make humans less boring

Tags: humans, fantasy-races

We all know how typically different species are portrayed in fantasy. Elves are frail, dexterous, magical, sophisticated; orcs strong, brutal, barbaric; dwarfs hard, sturdy, drink a lot and so on and on. But what with humans? They are Jack-of-all at best, or fantatical ignorant breeders at worst. I would very like to have ALL races have some special quirks and have something that make them stand out between others in some fields.

Question:
**How to escape this typical cliché and have interesting humans?**

Comment: This generally only occurs if you monoculture the humans like you're monoculturing the other fantasy races.

Comment: Study the warriors from the past: Nords, Celts, Spartans. You will see they are not boring at all. Check out ancient Vedic warriors, like Arjuna. He could fight entire armies with his bow.

Comment: Humans are boring to you? Read the news from Florida!

Comment: Read some non-fantasy novels and biographies. That may give you ideas for non-boring writing about humans.

Comment: ah here found it [related to your question](https://i.imgur.com/rEK4AIG.jpeg)

Comment: here another one the [TLDR](https://i.imgur.com/7vMgy8A.jpg) version of human ability.

Comment: Is our ingenuity, adaptability, and competitiveness, and gregariousness really that uninteresting? Humans have adapted to live in every biome on the planet. We self-organize into large, competitive societies which force continual advancement, unlike elves who are content to all hold hands peacefully, or orcs who only have disorganized, personal disputes. Humans' simultaneous desire to care for some humans and kill other humans has resulted in a pretty interesting society.

Comment: @LiJun if you only posted it as an answer... Give some thoughts anyway, thanks.

Comment: Stereotyping an ethnicity is generally considered insulting. If I were an orc I would take exception to your blanket statement that all orcs are brutal barbarians; I am certain that there are orcish artists and dreamy poets. If I were a dwarf I would take exception with your assertion that all dwarves are drunkards. I am certain that there must be some tee-total dwarves. And such stereotyping is rich coming from a human, when it is well known that humans are boisterous immoral cunning schemers.

Comment: You make humans less or more boring through *story*. Same with the other races. Is a tall pointy eared person really interesting? No, it's not. Not even when you call them "elf". But it depends on how you describe them. You could heap more and more features on the race but if the elf doesn't *do* anything interesting, the character would never be interesting. And vice versa - you could have the most standard of races - humans and *only* humans and make them compelling. Evidence: look at *most of fiction we have*. Also, non-fiction - historic characters and contemporary figures are also popular

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your design process for a non-human humanoid species seems to be to take a human, exaggerate a couple human traits into extremes, perhaps add a non-human superpower (like magic ability) and take that character as the stereotype for that species. The result is that the "regular" humans remain as the only non-stereotyped species which makes them seem weakly defined.

A possible solution to that is to pick one trait of human nature and make **all** other species devoid of that trait. Now that trait is the inherently human trait in your world. Which trait could that be? That's up to you. Think a bit about what is actually a typical "human" thing compared to all the other animals in the real world.

- Perhaps humans are the only species that has a concept of personal
  property?
- Perhaps humans are the only species that forms organisations with multiple hierarchy levels?
- Perhaps humans are the only species that practices monogamy?
- Perhaps humans are the only species that  worships a god or gods (who might or might not intervene in your world)?

The options are only limited by what traits you can not take away from any other species without ruining the story you want to tell.

You could also take one of the other classic Tolkien fantasy species, remove them from your world and replace their role with the humans.

- Maybe there are no elves, so the humans are the most intellectual species?
- Maybe there are no orcs, so the humans are the most warlike species?
- Maybe there are no dwarves, so the humans are the most hard-working and hard-partying species?

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with humans is that they're the baseline for comparison. They're boring from familiarity.

If you write the story from the point of view of one of the other races, then that race becomes the one that's dull by familiarity and you get to emphasise the advantages that humans have over them.

It's all a matter of point of view.

Comment: This would work only in case I could force this point of view, which isn't always the case.

Comment: @Guywithjewels'names, start the story with the dwarf or orc character. Introduce their culture and only raise species later when comparing to the humans they've just encountered.

Comment: I've meant situation in RPG for example, when I have party full of different races.

Comment: @Guywithjewels'names, humans are more robust than elves, more dextrous than orcs, taller than dwarves, and often more creative than any of them as the others are traditionally stagnant monocultures.